# Error with Vue-CLI Component : You are using the runtime-only build of Vue where the template compiler is not available

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-loader

New to VueJS and was going through the tutorial. Here are the steps i did

- Created Project using VUE CLI
- Tried to Create a component with this code.

  ```
   var data = {
      items: [{ text: 'Bananas', checked: true },
          { text: 'Apples', checked: false }
          ],
      title: 'My Shopping List',
      newItem: ''
          }; 

  Vue.component('items-component', {
      data: function () {
          return data;
      },
      template: `
  <div class="blog-post">
    <span>sample</span>
  </div>
  `
  });
  ```
- Added this to App.vue template part.

  ```
    <items-component></items-component>
  ```

However i am getting this error

```
[Vue warn]: You are using the runtime-only build of Vue where the template compiler is not available. Either pre-compile the templates into render functions, or use the compiler-included build.
```

**Questions**

- Is there a way we can create multiple components in a Vue Cli Project in one
  file or multiple files are the only way to create the components?.
- is manual editing webpack with CLI a good option?. If so, are there
  any    good links for the same.

Please let me know

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same error on my project. I solved it by:

1. creating a new file: `vue.config.js`
2. and added:

   ```
   module.exports = {
     runtimeCompiler: true
   }
   ```

Regarding your question, I'll try to answer even though I might not give the best answer:

> Is there a way we can create multiple components in a Vue Cli Project
>   in one file or multiple files are the only way to create the
>   components?

People always create multiple files for components.

I hope this helps

Comment: Where to create the file `vue.config.js` ? Then how to use it ?

Comment: In the root directory @IstiaqueAhmed